# Geode Native Client Composite Key

Tags: composite, geode

I am trying to figure out how I would create a composite KEY with the geode native client APIs.  Does someone have a simple example of how I would do this in .NET?  For example, say my data class is:

```
MyDataObject

string field1;
string field2;
string field3;
```

I want a composite key on `field1` and `field2`. What would this look like in C# .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a string of field1.field2 as the key. Although a key can also be the whole object. But I use strings for keys and build composite keys out of strings as said.

So your region type would be:

```
IRegion<String, MyDataObject>
```

Comment: Thanks.   I was able to find an example in the .net client examples.  The "key" object has to implement IDataSerializable, ICacheableKey.